# Show/Hide div tags within an ASP Repeater C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, show-hide

I want to be able to show /hide "div tags" based on user roles.

Some people will see somethings and others will not. This is easy outside of the repeater. Obviously `d1.Visible = false;` does not work.

I have searched the web including Stack and to no avail. It is more of an issue of which direction would be appropriate.

Code - Inline--

```
protected void Eng_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

sqlInv = "Select Item1, Item2, Item3, From Table";

IDataReader reader6 = DatabaseHelper.GetReader(string.Empty, sqlInv);


    Repeater1.DataSource = reader6;

        Repeater1.DataBind();

        reader6.Close();

}
```

html

```
asp:Repeater runat="server" id="Repeater1">

itemtemplate>

div>
div id="d1" runat="server"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Item1") %>/div>

<div id="d2" runat="server"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Item2") %>/div>

div id="d3" runat="server"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Item3") %>/div>


/itemtemplate>

/asp:Repeater>


/div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" id="Repeater1" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">

protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType.Equals(ListItemType.AlternatingItem) || e.Item.ItemType.Equals(ListItemType.Item))
        {
            //You can hide/show disable/enable your div
            Control div1 = e.Item.FindControl("div1");
            //get role here and check 
            // if role != admin 
           div1.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply and direction Mike. Before your reply, I decided to try a very similar approach. As follows: 
    protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)

```
if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType ==       ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {




        // Show or hid div here
        System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl div1 = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl)e.Item.FindControl("div1");

        System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl div2 = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl)e.Item.FindControl("div2");

        System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl div3 = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl)e.Item.FindControl("div3");

Also changed the test for the reader.
the reader is checking the DB for a RoleId but the problem was when the reader
```

was empty or null, the page blew up.

```
I changed to test if the reader had a record or not.
     if (reader6a.Read())
        {
            div1.Visible = true;
            div2.Visible = false;
            div3.Visible = false;
        }
    else
{
and so on
}
```